# Is there an algorithm to solve the following point clustering problem?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, linear-programming

[According to this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143473/formulate-a-2-clustering-problem-in-lp)

Given $n$ points $P=\{p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n\}$ in 2D space, and a matrix $D^{n\times n}$ with the distances between each pair of points, we want to partition the points into two clusters so as to minimize the  clusters' diameters.

This can be formulated as an [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem as follows:

- Let the diameter of first cluster $C_1$ be $r_1$.
- Let the diameter of the second cluster $C_2$ be $r_2$.
- For all points $p_i$, let $x_i=1$ if $p_i \in C_1$, else $x_i=-1$.
- Determine $min\hspace{4pt} r_1+r_2$ such that

  - $\frac{1}{2}(x_i+x_j) D(i,j)\leq r_1 \hspace{5pt}\forall p_i,p_j$
  - $-\frac{1}{2}(x_i+x_j) D(i,j)\leq r_2 \hspace{5pt}\forall p_i,p_j$
  - $x_i\in\{-1,1\}.$

My questions: is there a way to relax above ILP to find a approximation factor, and after relation how i can find the approximation factor?

Comment: This linear programming problem has $|P|+2$ variables, so I doubt it can solve it, considering the title of the paper is "[...] Linear Programming in $\mathbb{R}^3$ [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the natural LP relaxation of this problem, i.e., $ -1 \leq x_{i} \leq 1$ for every $x_i \in \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$.

Then, using the relaxation techniques, no approximation algorithm is possible since the integrality gap for this LP is $\infty$.

**Proof:** Consider any instance of this problem that has a non-zero cost. Then, in the relaxed LP, you make $x_i = 0$ for every $x_i \in \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$. The optimal cost of the fractional solution will be $0$. Here the ratio of the optimal integral to the fractional solution is $\infty$; therefore the integrality gap is $\infty$.

Read more about [integrality gap](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/392/the-importance-of-integrality-gap#:%7E:text=Integrality%20gaps%20essentially%20represent%20the,better%20than%20an%20x%2Dapproximation.) here.

Comment: What about the running time of above LP? suppose the integrality  gap is constant. Can it be solved in $o(n^3)$?

Comment: @MohammadRostami Yeah...I am not sure if the above ILP can be solved efficiently.

Comment: @MohammadRostami To discuss the integrality gap, you will first need to define some relaxed LP. Many LP relaxations are possible if extra constraints are introduced.

Comment: @MohammadRostami Why are you trying LP based approach to obtain $o(n^3)$ running time. Other simple methods should be there.

Comment: @MohammadRostami I am thinking... :)

Comment: Search for a paper with title "Minimizing the sum of diameters
efficiently".

Comment: @MohammadRostami If you do not want two points $u$ and $v$ in the same cluster, update the edge weight of $(u,v)$ to $\infty$ and apply the standard algorithm for $2$-clustering